# Parent class using method from child

Tags: c++

Is there a way I can use child methods with a parent class pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
class Parent {
public:

    int a;

    virtual int ret() {
        return a;
    }
};

class Child: public Parent {
    int b;

public:
    int ret() {
        return a;
    }

    int retB() {
        return b;
    }
};

void main() {
    Parent* parent = new Child();

    parent->retB();
}
```

Im using an array of Parent pointers with derived classes as members.
Is there a simple solution to this or should i just rethink my code?

Comment: You cannot invoke child's class method from a parent's pointer. You'd have to cast that pointer either using `static_cast<>` or `dynamic_cast<>`. Something like `static_cast<Child*>(parent)->retB()` will work, but only if you're certain that `parent` points to `Child` object. If you're unsure, always use `dynamic_cast<>` and check it's return value for `nullptr`

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve. Why are you not just overriding `ret` to return `b`?

Comment: In C++, we speak of base (Parent) and derived (Child) classes. A base class is not supposed to know anything about classes derived from it - if it does need to, your design is suspect.

Comment: You would need to cast the pointer type using reinterpret_cast

Comment: @PaulGötzinger You would almost never want to `reinterpret_cast` things...

Answer (score 2):

Out of the blue? **No**.

With certain checks? **Yes**.

What do I mean by that? Suppose you have a following class hierarchy:

```
struct Base {};
struct DerOne : Base {};
struct DerTwo : Base {};
```

Then you create a pointer of `Base` type to some derived class:

```
Base* b_ptr = new DerTwo();
```

It compiles correctly. Now imagine you want to call `DerTwo`'s imaginary method. In your world, it may be ok, but why it's not?

There would have to be some checks, whether or not what `b_ptr` points to actually implements the method you want to invoke. These checks are not automatically performed. In `C++` you don't pay for what you don't need. It'd be pointless to have those kind of checks every time we call any method via a pointer.

So how can you achieve it?

You have to ensure that `b_ptr` points to something that implements the method you want to invoke. How?

#### `static_cast` vs `dynamic_cast`:

Base class' pointer **cannot** invoke methods that are not declared in Base class. That's a fact. Done. If you wish to invoke some method from Derived class, you need to change the type of the pointer. How you do that? You either use `static_cast<>` or `dynamic_cast<>`. [Here you can read more about C++ casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used), but for now, I will tl;dr this question and answer for your specific example.

**Option #1**: You *know* that type pointed to by `b_ptr` is of a certain class (let's assume we're talking about `DerTwo`) and you want to invoke a `foo()` method declared inside it.

You use `static_cast<>`. You use it because you know and are certain that there is a specific, derived type object pointed to by a base class pointer. Regarding our example, it'd look like this:

```
Base* b_ptr = new DerTwo();
DerTwo* der_ptr = static_cast<DerTwo*>(b_ptr);

der_ptr->foo(); // b_ptr and der_ptr point to the same object
```

**Option #2:** You *don't know* the type of the object pointed by `b_ptr` and want to check if it's safe to call `foo()`.

Suppose that `foo()` is declared **only** in `DerTwo`. Thus, if `b_ptr` points to `DerOne` object and you'd want to call `foo()`, terrible things would happen. You'd call a non-existing method. You *have to* perform a check, via `dynamic_cast<>`:

```
Base* b_ptr = new DerTwo();
DerTwo* der_ptr = dynamic_cast<DerTwo*>(b_ptr);

if(der_ptr != nullptr){
    der_ptr->foo(); // b_ptr and der_ptr again point to the same object
} else {
    // b_ptr somehow does NOT point to DerTwo object
}
```

`dynamic_cast<>` performs a check, whether or not it's argument actually points to the object of specified type. It it does, it returns a pointer of the specified type to the object. If it fails, it returns `nullptr`, so all you have to do to check if your *dynamic casting* succeeded, is compare it's result to `nullptr`.